# r.js is not creating the build file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I created a sample program using backbone.js and require.js. I am trying to optimize using this program r.js. but it is not working in Ubuntu 14. It is working fine in Windows.

Sample program:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>        
    </head>
    <body>
     <div>Testing</div>
     <script data-main="js/init" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

init.js

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery: 'libs/jquery',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone'
  }
});

require(['underscore', 'backbone', 'app'],
function(_, Backbone, app) {
    console.log(app);
    app.start();
});
```

app.js

```js
define(['underscore', 'backbone'],
function(_, Backbone) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        start: function() {
            console.log('APP');
        }
    };
});
```

I want to optimize this using r.js
I installed r.js using npm install -g requirejs

build.js

```js
({
    baseUrl : "js",
    name: "init",
    out: "build/init-built.js"
})
```

Command to run the optimization: r.js -o build.js 
Nothing happens after executing this command.

Please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Please tell me the reason for downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by uninstalling and installing nodejs.